# CMake Error: Unsupported architecture -- ppc64. On PowerPC Ubuntu

Tags: cmake, powerpc, tarantool

I have PowerMac G5. I install Lubuntu xenial on it. Now I try to [build database Tarantool from source](https://tarantool.org/doc/dev_guide/building_from_source.html#building-from-source). 
Onthe step `cmake .` I have the following error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - big endian
CMake Error at cmake/arch.cmake:19 (message):
  Unsupported architecture -- ppc64,
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:46 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/zlon/tarantool/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/zlon/tarantool/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

**Is it possible to fix this error or have have no chances with Linux on PowerPC?**

Comment: Futher messages at the error point ([cmake/arch.cmake:19](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/blob/1.7/cmake/arch.cmake#L19))  explain the error: They do not support big-endian platforms.

Comment: I found how to skip this test, but now i have "undefined reference to `__atomic_compare_exchange_8"

Comment: Skipping the test probably won't do you much good: The library simply does not support your platform. That check was probably there for a reason. So what you would need to do is perform a proper port of the full thing to PowerPC, which is likely not going to be a small effort (and will definitely be too big to discuss in the context of a SO question).